# Making api calls from inside forEach for every element and getting values in Angular using Observable

Tags: angular, observable

I want to iterate through an array and want to make subsequent api calls , and to display that elements related value

```
currentRefValue: any = [];
myArray.droppeditem = [];

somearray.forEach(element => { 
    let objTemp:any = {}

    objtemp.receivedValue = 
    someFunction(element.elementId,element.elementName)

    myArray.droppeditem.push(objTemp);
 })

someFunction(eId,ename){

  let parentObj = this.getExisitingParentObj(eId);

  let parentEquip = parentObj.map(equip => equip.entities.filter(entity => 
  entity.entities.length > 0)[0])[0];

 let ref = this.helperService.getPointId(this.someExisitngObject, 
 ['current', 'desired'], parentEquip.referenceIDs)[0];

 let subs = this.siteService.getPointData(ref, 'current')
                    .pipe(
                        map(this.helperService.stripHaystackTypeMapping),
                    )
                    .subscribe(({ rows }) => {
                        if (rows.length > 0) {
                            this.currentRefValue[ename] = rows[0].val;
                        }
                    });                 
    //someCalculations
    return this.currentRefValue;                    
 }
```

The subsequent api call(**this.siteService.getPointData**) expects value from the previous api call(**this.helperService.getPointId**) and the previous(**this.helperService.getPointId**) inturn already has parentEquip object . I want to call someFunction from inside foreach loop as I have to get currentRefValue of each element

Html

```
<div *ngFor="let existingItem of myArray.droppeditem">

 <span>existingItem.receivedValue</span>

</div>
```

Comment: is `existingItem.recievedValue` an Observable?

Comment: existingItem is an array which I have created in ts, inside which I am expecting values from somefunction and in html I want to show value existingItem.recievedValue for each element

Comment: Sorry but you mix two diferent level of your application:

Comment: @DmitriyIvanko, Please could you elaborate, or what changes needs to be made , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't return what you think it does:

```
objtemp.receivedValue = someFunction(element.elementId,element.elementName)
```

`this.currentRefValue` is always returned before any http-request is finished. Instead inside the subscribe block push data to your array. Here's a simplified sample of your code, since we don't know what all things you do in your code, but it should be handled like this:

```ts
this.elements.map(element => {
 // do stuff before http-request
  this.myService.getPointData().pipe(
    map(data => {
      // do stuff with received data and then push to array
      this.myObj.droppedItem.push({ receivedValue: data[0].val });
    })
  ).subscribe();
});
```

**[STACKBLIZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8xehz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

You could also use `forkJoin` to run all these requests in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, I had one query like instead of making api calls within the foreach can i not move these api call into another function and return the value from that function as I have given in someFunction

Comment: If you want a more specific answer you need to provide a [mcve], you can do that by forking my stackblitz with your actual usecase, and I'm happy to take a look at it :)